# git merge multiple branch then selectively undo

Tags: git, merge, undo, revert

This might be because of a wrong work process, but here is the situation.
I am in the testing team, and I merged 20 branches to the master to test each features(each branch represents a feature). I found 5 branches were not good with bugs, and only want to push the 15 good branches. Since I went through solving 10 or so conflicts, I don't want to go back to the original point before 20 branch merging.

Q: How do I undo those 5 bug branch commits and only push 15 good ones?

Comment: you may want to look into [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere)

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using TortoiseGit, which does not support that command. any other options or suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

> unfortunately, I'm using TortoiseGit, which does not support that command.

Actually, it can support it, in that the `git merge` triggered by TortoiseGit will take advantages of `git rerere` already recorded conflict resolution.

So it is still to your advantage to setup rerere:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

TortoiseGit merge will detect it and use it.

But in your case, [an interactive rebase (with TortoiseGit)](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html) would allow you to drop the wrong commit, and keep the 15 good ones.

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/GitRebase.png]